# What does a pipe character in python slice notation do?

Tags: python

In python slice notation for lists and tuples, I noticed that a pipe character doesn't throw an error.  I'm not sure what exactly it does though, as the results seem a little random.

```
testA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

#### Given that

```
testA[0:3]
```

#### gives

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

#### and

```
testA[4:6]
```

#### gives

[5, 6]

#### What does this pipe do?

```
testA[0:3|4:6]
```

#### it gives

[1, 7]

Any ideas?

Comment: @gspr I guess that begs the question, what does bitwise-or do with slices?

Comment: @gspr I don't think this is a duplicate. It was answered below, I could not have come to that conclusion from the answer offered as a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
testA[0:3|4:6]
```

evaluates as

```
testA[0 : (3 | 4) : 6]
```

Which, in turn, evaluates via bitwise-or to

```
testA[0 : 7 : 6]
```

And this corresponds to the range `0 : 7` with a step size of 6. Hence only the first and last index are used.